# OpenGL ES 2.0 shader integer operations

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I am having trouble with getting integer operations working in the OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders.

```
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
```

One the example lines where I'm having issues is: `color.r = floor(f / 65536);`
I get this error:

```
Error linking program: ERROR:SEMANTIC-4 (vertex shader, line 13) Operator not supported for operand types
```

To give more context to what's happening, within the library that I am working with the only way to pass the color is as a float to which 3 integers have been bit shifted into. 3 (8-bit) int -> float pass to shader | float - > r g b (using integer manipulation) this all works fine on the normal OpenGL but having trouble making this work on the raspberry pi.

Full vexter shader code here:

```
attribute vec4 position;

varying vec3 Texcoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

vec3 unpackColor(float f) 
{
    vec3 color;
    f -= 0x1000000;
    color.r = floor(f / 65536);
    color.g = floor((f - color.r * 65536) / 256.0);
    color.b = floor(f - color.r * 65536 - color.g * 256.0);

    return color / 256.0;
}

void main()
{
    Texcoord = unpackColor(position.w);
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: You might need .0 on the literal floats.

Comment: Diving by 65536 (16-bit int) allows to offset the values by 16-bits to get the red colour integer value out. If 65536 is turned into 65536.0 would that still keep it at 16-bits?

Comment: @user1031204 vec3 is a float data type in glsl.